# Remove unwanted letter in data column names in R environment

Tags: r, r-environment

I have a dataset the contains a large number of columns every column has a name of date in the form of x2019.10.10

what I want is to remove the x letter and change the type of the date to be 2019-10-10

How this could be done in the R environment?

Comment: Please check [previously asked questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15589/remove-part-of-string-in-r). Information on how to solve these kind of problems is readily available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be:

1. Get rid of `x`
2. Replace `.` with `-`.

Here I create a `dataframe` that has similar columns to yours:

```
df = data.frame(x2019.10.10 = c(1, 2, 3),
                x2020.10.10 = c(4, 5, 6))
df

  x2019.10.10 x2020.10.10
1           1           4
2           2           5
3           3           6
```

And then, using `dplyr` (looks much tidier):

```
library(dplyr)
names(df) = names(df) %>% 
        gsub("x", "", .) %>% # Get rid of x and then (%>%):
        gsub("\\.", "-", .) # replace "." with "-"
df

  2019-10-10 2020-10-10
1          1          4
2          2          5
3          3          6
```

If you do not want to use `dplyr`, here is how you would do the same thing in `base R`:

```
names(df) = gsub("x", "", names(df))
names(df) = gsub("\\.", "-", names(df))
df

  2019-10-10 2020-10-10
1          1          4
2          2          5
3          3          6
```

Comment: If you want to go ugly and unreadable, you can also do `names(df) = gsub("x", "", gsub("\\.", "-", names(df))`